# Simplify this if statement

Tags: javascript

Is there a way this if statement can be simplified. I find I am in this senario alot and want to make it cleaner.

```
if (item === 'christie' || item === 'chris') {
   return 'christine';
}
if (item === 'maddy' || item === 'madison') {
   return 'madeline';
}

return '';
```

I created an example for the sake of the question but is there a simpler way?

Comment: You might prefer a `switch` statement with fallthroughs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit longer but easier to quickly grasp what's going on. According to me atleast.

```js
switch(item) {
  case 'christie':
  case 'chris':
    return 'christine';
  case 'maddy':
  case 'madison':
    return 'madeline';
  default:
    return '';
}
```

Here's another option using `includes`

```js
if(['christie','chris'].includes(item)) {
 return 'christine';
}

if(['maddy','madison'].includes(item)) {
 return 'madeline';
}

return '';
```

Answer (score 2):

One option assuming the names you provided are the only name options and the returned value is according to the prefix.

```
return item.startsWith('chr') ? 'christine' : item.startsWith('mad') ? 'madeline' : '';
```

If you want to stay with `if` you can use:

```
if (item.startsWith('chr')) return 'christine';
if (item.startsWith('mad')) return 'madeline';
return '';
```

Comment: That will work only if the inputs are always in those four names, but will detect `madness` as `madeline` and `chrome` as `christine`...

Comment: Correct, and I clearly made that assumption at the first line. This solution is just to give an idea of further optimization.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a switch statement

```
function switch_names(item) {
  switch (item) {
    case "christie":
    case "chris":
      return "christine";
    case "maddy":
    case "madison":
      return "madeline";
    default:
      return "";
  }
}
const name=switch_names("chris")
console.log(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the use case it can be simpler to do something like the following:

```js
const name_map = {
  'christie': 'christine',
  'chris': 'christine',
  'maddy': 'madeline',
  'madison': 'madeline',
};

const map_name = (name) => name_map[name] ? name_map[name] : name;

console.log('christie', map_name('christie'));
console.log('christine', map_name('christine'));
console.log('maddy', map_name('maddy'));
```

If you wanted to specify the name relationship the other way around you could probably do something like:

```js
const name_map = {
  'christine': ['christie', 'chris'],
  'madeline': ['maddy', 'madison'],
};

const flip = (obj) => Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce(
    (acc1, [name, alts]) => alts.reduce(
      (acc2, alt) => ({ ...acc2, [alt]: name }),
      acc1
    ),
    {}
  )

const flipped_name_map = flip(name_map);

const map_name = (name) => flipped_name_map[name] ? flipped_name_map[name] : name;

console.log('christie', map_name('christie'));
console.log('christine', map_name('christine'));
console.log('maddy', map_name('maddy'));
console.log('madison', map_name('madison'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (item === 'christie' || item === 'chris' ||item === 'maddy' || item === 'madison') 
{
   return item;
}
return '';
```

Your post was very unclear, what do you want exactly?

Comment: Not quite. The OP wants to map `'christie'` and `'chris'` to `'christine'` and `'maddy'` and `'madison'` to `madeline`...